# Add a row to the table to display a title using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a row to a table and display a text using only JavaScript. I have tried the following code to attempt the layout pictured below.

[image: two rows of squares]

```js
var abcArray = ["#800000","#A36386", "#FFD4D8", "#223CFF", "#F5FF5A", 
"#FF5555", "#A7EBFF"];

var table = document.getElementById("titleTxt");

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var txt = document.createTextNode("some value");

td.appendChild(txt);
tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
```

```css
body{font-size:30px;
font-family: "Arial", "sans-serif";}

table {
margin-top:50px;
background-color:white;
border: 1px solid black;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
width:50%
}

td {
width: 700px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.spanrows1,
.spanrows2 {
 text-align: center;
}  

.spanrows1 {
width: 400px;
}

.spanrows2 {
width: 600px;
}

.span2rows {
text-align: left;
}

.squareDivs {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:#000000;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
display: inline-block;
}

.squareTxt {
line-height: 100px;
vertical-align: middle;    
}

.alignTxt{text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alignTxt"><span id="titleTxt"></span></div>

<table>
<tr>
 <td class='spanrows2'>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no EventListener declared, you should place your JS under your HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lab Report</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body> 

<div class="alignTxt"><span id="titleTxt"></span></div>

<table>
<tr>
 <td class='spanrows2'>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
    <div class='squareDivs'><span class='squareTxt'></span></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
**<script src="myScript.js"></script>**
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. removed your css. It's not necessary in this question/example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your *javascript* goes inside a `<script>` tag either by placing it in its own file such as "myScript.js" (as per your example), or by putting the code in its own tag as shown. This would normally go in the `<head>` section:

```
<script>
/*!
Your jQuery and javascript codes here
*/

function run() {
    var abcArray = ["#800000","#A36386", "#FFD4D8", "#223CFF", "#F5FF5A", 
    "#FF5555", "#A7EBFF"];

    var table = document.getElementById("titleTxt");

    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("some value");

    td.appendChild(txt);
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
}

window.addEventListener("load", run, false);
</script>
```

Also you need to run the script once the [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) has loaded or the element wont be available on the page when your script runs to add your new elements to.

In the sample above a function was added to update the table and that function is added to the things to be run once the page is loaded.

[Documentation on the load event](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)

Comment: thanks for the advice and help. However, the table row is not displayed in the way that the assignment asked for. The row needs to attached above the current table and have the same border and width. In the row, a text is to be displayed towards the left "Question number 1: 1". How do I modify the above code?

Comment: Sorry but this seems like the question has changed into "do my homework for me".

Comment: You seem to have changed the original question to something that is less functional than before. I think to get it do do what you want you are going to have to try to understand at a minimum how the basic parts of an HTML document are structured `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` and where you need to place `<script>` and `<style>` tags, or alternatively how to include external scripts and style tags with `<script scr="..."></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`.